# android - can't change layout

Tags: android

I make a condition when the client receives the word "login success" then the first layout will be changed to the second layout.

The first layout is controlled by **Client_layoutActivity class** and

The second layout is controlled by **chat_wall class** class

I think this method is 100% correct because I've successfully tried before but when the conditions are met (received "login success"), the layout still does not change. I am looking for a solution on google but still not get the appropriate answers.
I use the method as shown below:

```
if (line.contentEquals("login success")){

        Toast.makeText(this, "login success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent i = new Intent(Client_layoutActivity.this, chat_wall.class);
        startActivity(i);
        chat_wall cw = new chat_wall();
        cw.send(out, in);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read basics of android in more details, in this application if you need to switch between two activities:
then do the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Client_layoutActivity.this, chat_wall.class);
startActivity(i);
```

if you want to pass some data to other activity, use putExtra method of Intent, to do the same.

Comment: putExtra method accepts values in key-value pair, so if you are sending two values, invoke two putExtra with perspecitve key.

Answer (score 0):

just check once the

```
setContentView(R.layout.chat_wall_layout);
```

is setted or not, in chat_wall activity.

also try

```
Intent i = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), chat_wall.class);
```

Comment: do just 1 thing, remove  chat_wall cw = new chat_wall();
        cw.send(out, in);
  and try it

Comment: are u gettin any ERROR in log-cat? or not?

Comment: most wel-come n don say thanks, I was free, so I helped u, simple

Comment: ha3x... Your very humble :) thnks